# How to keep receiving the data when app is sent to background mode?

Tags: ios

In iOS12 apple started canceling network requests if they are not `URLSessionDownloadTask` and setup with background session.

But according to the apple website:

> You don’t have to do all background network activity with background
>   sessions... Apps that declare appropriate
>   background modes can use default URL sessions and data tasks, just as
>   if they were in the foreground

I'm streaming media file with a custom player, application has `Audio` and `Background Fetch` modes enabled. `URLSessionDataTask` is initialized in foreground as soon as app enters background state task is canceled.

I'm aware that AVPlayer can stream in the background but using AVPlayer is not an option.

I'm aware that I can setup session with `URLSessionDownloadTask` which will download data in separate process and return path to file, which is not an option due the the streaming requirement.

I'm aware that I can request additional background execution time with `UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask` but it's not acceptable solution because if `backgroundTimeRemaining` expires before stream finished app will be killed.

Is there any way to keep receiving data when app is in the background mode?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that your “custom player” is keeping the app running in the background and that the app isn’t being suspended?

Comment: yes. It plays for as long as there data in the buffer, after that it stops.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your background session has [`shouldUseExtendedBackgroundIdleMode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration/1409517-shoulduseextendedbackgroundidlem) enabled. If you don’t, the session will stop data tasks when the app transitions from foreground execution to background execution. Or, as that [Downloading Files in the Background](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/downloading_files_in_the_background) document says, you can use [`default`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration/1411560-default) session configurations, too, which don’t exhibit this behavior.

---

FWIW, when using `AVPlayer`, in addition to enabling background audio capability ...

[image]

... you may also have to tell the shared audio session instance that it’s active:

```
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback)
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
```

I can’t say what your “custom player” requires, but for me I had to do both of these to keep the app running in the background, playing audio, with `AVPlayer`.

Comment: Tested with `shouldUseExtendedBackgroundIdleMode` set to `true`, it keeps connection alive while app in the background state (but it looks like download is paused), as soon as device is locked connection is cancelled. I'm aware that when using AVPlayer system keeps connection alive, I'm suspecting that AVPlayer has special permissions.

Here is the link to test project, if you'd like to check project setup / see described behavior. https://www.dropbox.com/s/iljpunkkzi47t4l/DataTaskExample.zip